# Постоянное соединение для HTTPS запроса

Tags: lua

В сети я нашёл парочку примеров, как выполнить HTTPS запрос. Однако все они обладают очень серьёзным недостатком: они закрывают TCP соединение, как только получат от сервера все данные. Это никуда не годится.

Вот один из примеров

```
https = require('ssl.https')
local data, code = https.request('https://httpbin.org/get')
```

Как его бы дополнить с минимальной болью, чтобы соединение не закрывалось?

Comment: Ищите "постоянное соединение http", "http keep alive", "http connection reuse". может есть опция, чтобы сделать ваш http постоянным и вызывать запрос за запросом, не разрывая соединение.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, `LuaSocket` не поддерживает постоянные соединения для http(s), поэтому надо либо на сокетах писать самому, либо искать другую библиотеку.

Comment: @zed, не могли бы тогда подсказать, на какую библиотеку обратить внимание?

Comment: `Lua-cURL` должна быть хорошей альтернативой: https://github.com/Lua-cURL/Lua-cURLv3

Comment: @zed, да, спасибо, кажется, это работает. Может, стоит это оформить как ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Библиотека `LuaSocket` (которая используется в коде из примера) не поддерживает постоянные соединения по http(s). Поэтому, минимальной болью не обойтись и надо использовать какую-то другую библиотеку.

К примеру, можно взять [Lua-cURL](https://github.com/Lua-cURL/Lua-cURLv3):

```
local curl = require "cURL"

local function main()

  local e = curl.easy()

  -- включает подробный вывод о ходе соединения
  e:setopt_verbose(true)

  e:setopt_url("https://httpbin.org/get")
  e:perform() -- выполняет загрузку и НЕ закрывает соединение

  -- отключает переиспользование соединений
  e:setopt_forbid_reuse(true)

  e:setopt_url("https://httpbin.org/ip")
  e:perform() -- выполняет загрузку и закрывает соединение

  e:close()
end

main()
```

В этой библиотеке наоборот, соединения по-умолчанию не закрываются и переиспользуются (даже после вызова `e:close`) и тут надо использовать специальную опцию [CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE.html), чтобы соединения разрывались (если это нужно).

Весь процесс открытия/переиспользования/закрытия соединений можно наблюдать в логе:

```
*   Trying 23.22.14.18...
* Connected to httpbin.org (23.22.14.18) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* NPN, negotiated HTTP1.1
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*    subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; OU=EssentialSSL Wildcard; CN=*.httpbin.org
*    start date: Jan 12 00:00:00 2016 GMT
*    expire date: Jan 19 23:59:59 2017 GMT
*    subjectAltName: httpbin.org matched
*    issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /get HTTP/1.1
Host: httpbin.org
Accept: */*

{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org"
  }, 
  "origin": "xx.xx.xx.xx", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Tue, 04 Oct 2016 19:46:13 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 154
< Connection: keep-alive
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< 
* Connection #0 to host httpbin.org left intact
* Found bundle for host httpbin.org: 0x95eac28 [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host httpbin.org
* Connected to httpbin.org (23.22.14.18) port 443 (#0)
> GET /ip HTTP/1.1
Host: httpbin.org
Accept: */*

{
  "origin": "xx.xx.xx.xx"
}
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Tue, 04 Oct 2016 19:46:13 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 33
< Connection: keep-alive
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

После выполнения первого запроса `curl` сообщает, что соединение оставлено открытым:

```
Connection #0 to host httpbin.org left intact
```

Перед выполнением второго запроса, оно его находит и радостно переиспользует:

```
Found bundle for host httpbin.org: 0x95eac28 [can pipeline]
Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host httpbin.org
```

А вот после второго запроса, из-за того, что в примере перед вторым запросом указан запрет на переиспользование соединений, оно закрывается:

```
Closing connection 0
```

Comment: К LuaSocket можно прикрутить поддержку keep-alive, но придется частично переписать https.request.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за пример. Верно ли я понимаю, что функция, переданная как параметр writefunction, вызывается только один раз для одного запроса. Просто мне нужно получить тело и код ответа в переменных Lua. Правильно ли я это делаю? http://pastebin.com/2k8t2Lqb

Comment: @mymedia Нет, для каждого запроса эта функция может вызываться несколько раз и `body` надо накапливать. Посмотрите пример вот здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29844130/6219657

Comment: @mymedia Вот адаптированный пример: http://pastebin.com/q3Ks6uTP

Comment: спасибо, общая идея ясна

Answer (score 0):

На сокетах:

```
require("socket")
require("ssl")
-----

local params = {
   mode = "client",
   protocol = "tlsv1",
   verify = "none",
   options = { "all", "no_sslv2", "no_sslv3", "no_ticket", "no_compression" } 
}
-----------------------------

local url = 'https://httpbin.org/get'

local host, file = url:match("://(.+)(/.+)")
local headers = "HTTP/1.1\nHost: "..host.."\nConnection: keep-alive\n\n"
local conn = socket.tcp()
conn:connect(host, 443)

conn = ssl.wrap(conn, params)
conn:dohandshake()
conn:send( "GET ".. file.." "..headers )
--
    local  len, s, status = 0
    local str, answer = "",""
    while true do
          s, status = conn:receive('*l') 
          if s==nil or status =="closed" then   break end
          str=str..s..'\n'
          if s:find("Content%-Length")  then  len = s:match("Content%-Length:%s?(%d+)")   end
          if s=="" then 
              answer, status = conn:receive(len)      break 
          end
    end
    print(str)
    print(answer)   

conn:close()
```