# Рабочий пример мультиплексирования с cURL на PHP

Tags: php, сеть, curl, php-curl, http2

Не могу разобраться с тем как проверить работу мультиплексирования, и есть ли она при выполнении.

Добавляю в **curl_multi_exec()** 4 дексриптора **curl_init()**, которые выполняют запрос к одному домену. В логе **CURLOPT_VERBOSE** в каждых следующих от первого дескриптора, вижу следующую строку:

```
* Found bundle for host yandex.ru: 0x55adc86744f0 [serially]
```

ПОДРОБНЕЕ.

Пример:

```
    // создаем дескриптор cURL
    $ch1 = curl_init();

    // устанавливаем опции
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "https://yandex.ru");
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FILE, $curl1_exec);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_STDERR, $curl1_log);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);

    // создаем новый дескриптор копированием существующего
    $ch2 = curl_copy_handle($ch1);
    // устанавливаем новые опции
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "https://yandex.ru/all");
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FILE, $curl2_exec);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_STDERR, $curl2_log);

    // создаем новый дескриптор копированием существующего
    $ch3 = curl_copy_handle($ch1);
    // устанавливаем новые опции
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_URL, "https://yandex.ru/news/");
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_FILE, $curl3_exec);
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_STDERR, $curl3_log);

    // создаем новый дескриптор копированием существующего
    $ch4 = curl_copy_handle($ch1);
    // устанавливаем новые опции
    curl_setopt($ch4, CURLOPT_URL, "https://yandex.ru/images/?from=tabbar");
    curl_setopt($ch4, CURLOPT_FILE, $curl4_exec);
    curl_setopt($ch4, CURLOPT_STDERR, $curl4_log);

    //создаем набор дескрипторов cURL
    $mh = curl_multi_init();

    //добавляем дескрипторы
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch1);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch2);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch3);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch4);

    //добавляем попытку использовать мультиплексирование, если это возможно
    curl_multi_setopt($mh, CURLMOPT_PIPELINING, CURLPIPE_MULTIPLEX);

    //запускаем множественный обработчик
    do {
        $status = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        if ($active) {
            // Ждем какое-то время для оживления активности
            curl_multi_select($mh);
        }
    } while ($active && $status == CURLM_OK);

    //закрываем дескрипторы
    curl_multi_close($mh);
```

ИНФОРМАЦИЯ ПО СОЕДИНЕНИЯМ.

Первое:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://yandex.ru/
* Hostname 'yandex.ru' was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 77.88.55.60...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to yandex.ru (77.88.55.60) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=yandex.ru; O=Yandex LLC; OU=ITO; L=Moscow; ST=Russia; C=RU
*  start date: Sep  5 11:12:34 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Sep  4 11:12:34 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "yandex.ru" matched cert's "yandex.ru"
*  issuer: C=RU; O=Yandex LLC; OU=Yandex Certification Authority; CN=Yandex CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x556999495740)
> GET / HTTP/2
Host: yandex.ru
Accept: */*
```

Второе:

```
* Found bundle for host yandex.ru: 0x5569994ce320 [serially]
* Server doesn't support multi-use (yet)
* Hostname 'yandex.ru' was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 77.88.55.60...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to yandex.ru (77.88.55.60) port 443 (#1)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=yandex.ru; O=Yandex LLC; OU=ITO; L=Moscow; ST=Russia; C=RU
*  start date: Sep  5 11:12:34 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Sep  4 11:12:34 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "yandex.ru" matched cert's "yandex.ru"
*  issuer: C=RU; O=Yandex LLC; OU=Yandex Certification Authority; CN=Yandex CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55699949ea40)
> GET /all HTTP/2
Host: yandex.ru
Accept: */*
```

Comment: Судя по логам, в данном примере мультиплексирование не работает: `Server doesn't support multi-use (yet)`. Попробуйте сделать запросы на гугл, вместо яндекса.

Comment: @zed попробовал на google.com и на yahoo.com. Результат такой же: * Server doesn't support multi-use (yet)

Comment: @zed я правильно понимаю, что не важно из какого дескриптора cURL пойдет запрос к домену? Мультиплексирование все равно должно происходить?

В одном из вопросов: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572546 приводился пример использования Lua-cURL, которая возвращает такие строки: 

Found bundle for host httpbin.org: 0x95eac28 [can pipeline]
Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host httpbin.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере мультиплексирование не сработало, об этом говорит как минимум строчка `Connected to ... (#1)` во втором логе (в скобках указан номер соединения к данному хосту). А так же, то что повторно происходит TLS-рукопожатие.

Для теста, чтобы увидеть мультиплексирование в действии, ограничьте число соединений с сервером до 1, используя опцию `CURLMOPT_MAX_HOST_CONNECTIONS`.

Вот какой примерно лог должен получиться, когда мультиплексирование работает:

```
* Found bundle for host yandex.ru: 0x1d477a8 [serially]
* Server doesn't support multiplex (yet)
* Connection #0 is still name resolving, can't reuse
* No more connections allowed to host yandex.ru: 1
* No connections available.
* Found bundle for host yandex.ru: 0x1d477a8 [serially]
* Server doesn't support multiplex (yet)
* Connection #0 is still name resolving, can't reuse
* No more connections allowed to host yandex.ru: 1
* No connections available.
*   Trying 5.255.255.70:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to yandex.ru (5.255.255.70) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: G:/dev/msys32/mingw32/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=yandex.ru; O=Yandex LLC; OU=ITO; L=Moscow; ST=Russia; C=RU
*  start date: Sep  5 11:12:34 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Sep  4 11:12:34 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "yandex.ru" matched cert's "yandex.ru"
*  issuer: C=RU; O=Yandex LLC; OU=Yandex Certification Authority; CN=Yandex CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0

* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x1d37770)
> GET /all HTTP/2
Host: yandex.ru
Accept: */*

* Found bundle for host yandex.ru: 0x1d477a8 [can multiplex]
* Multiplexed connection found!
* Found connection 0, with 1 requests on it
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host yandex.ru
* Transfer was pending, now try another
* Using Stream ID: 3 (easy handle 0x1d3c898)
> GET /news/ HTTP/2
Host: yandex.ru
Accept: */*

* Found bundle for host yandex.ru: 0x1d477a8 [can multiplex]
* Multiplexed connection found!
* Found connection 0, with 2 requests on it
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host yandex.ru
* Transfer was pending, now try another
* Using Stream ID: 5 (easy handle 0x1d419c0)
> GET /images/?from=tabbar HTTP/2
Host: yandex.ru
Accept: */*

* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
< HTTP/2 302
< content-length: 0
< content-type: text/plain
< date: Sat, 28 Sep 2019 12:14:11 GMT
< location: https://yandex.by/images/?from=tabbar&rdrnd=81726&redircnt=156967285
1.1
< x-yandex-items-count: 30
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< set-cookie: yandexuid=5793565301569672851; path=/; domain=.yandex.ru; expires=
Thu, 31-Dec-2037 20:59:59 GMT
< set-cookie: i=qNCxtom97cEsA8UD8N95FpWH+3kBHHWfa3Qknvqzjw2kyyvxbSgXMBH/WFdA29/z
/yopQn/FrZ80Rsfj43BeU1ZSzyk=; Expires=Tue, 25-Sep-2029 12:14:11 GMT; Domain=.yan
dex.ru; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
<
< HTTP/2 200
< content-length: 72727
< content-security-policy: style-src 'unsafe-inline' https://yastatic.net;connec
t-src https://yandex.ru https://mc.admetrica.ru https://mc.yandex.ru;default-src
 'none';font-src https://yastatic.net;script-src 'unsafe-inline' https://yastati
c.net https://mc.yandex.ru;report-uri https://csp.yandex.net/csp?project=morda&f
rom=morda.big.ru&showid=1569672851.79748.122006.776086&h=sas2-0701-sas-portal-mo
rda-17154&csp=new&date=20190928&yandexuid=1030803431569672851;frame-src https://
mc.yandex.ru;img-src https://yastatic.net https://mc.yandex.ru data: https://yan
dex.ru https://mc.admetrica.ru 'self'
< date: Sat, 28 Sep 2019 12:14:11 GMT
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< set-cookie: yandexuid=1030803431569672851; Expires=Tue, 25-Sep-2029 12:14:11 G
MT; Domain=.yandex.ru; Path=/
< set-cookie: i=eOTzJeGXmxCjNGdYdiFXilW2ovcfoCamtMYnr75DHJTod24FA3t7/XQ0oPq7ocbb
7Cjf1l2qtypRQaj44c7lTlHoJKc=; Expires=Tue, 25-Sep-2029 12:14:11 GMT; Domain=.yan
dex.ru; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< x-frame-options: DENY
< expires: Sat, 28 Sep 2019 12:14:12 GMT
< p3p: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="NON DSP ADM DEV PSD IVDo OUR IND STP PHY PR
E NAV UNI"
< last-modified: Sat, 28 Sep 2019 12:14:12 GMT
< cache-control: no-cache,no-store,max-age=0,must-revalidate
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<
```

По логу видно, что второй и третий запрос не могут стартовать, пока соединение занято первым запросом. Так же, мультиплексирование не может стартовать пока не будет отресолвено имя хоста и не будет установлено хотя бы одно соединение. После того, как соединение устанавливается, curl отправляет первый запрос, и поскольку мультиплексирование разрешено, отправляет в рамках этого же соединения 2 оставшихся в очереди запроса.

А когда у curl нету ограничений на число соединений и ещё нету активных соединений, то ему проще открыть сразу несколько параллельных соединений и отправить запросы параллельно, не занимаясь мультиплексированием.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Сейчас вижу, что мультиплексирование работает. Еще помучаю его, т.к. пока не совсем разобрался)